# how to delete google cloud organization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

I created a google cloud identity organization account using my web domain and now i need to delete the organization (I want to create the organization in another account and have that account own the domain). 
None of the documentation helps. I can't delete the account from account view presumably because it is linked to the organization. I can't delete the org through billing because it's still in the free trial period and hasn't started billing yet -- at least there is no billing account. 
How do I delete the organization and start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to create an organization: as part of G Suite and as part of Cloud Identity.

For both types, the organization name is tied to the domain name. This cannot be changed. You can create a different G Suite or Cloud Identity account based upon another domain name that you own/control which will result in a new organization with a different name.

I think you have your ideas about organizations backward. Organizations own accounts (as in projects). Projects don't own organizations - they are children. Projects cannot be moved between organizations.

Billing accounts don't own organizations and organizations don't own billing accounts - they are just linked.

Therefore, there is no need to delete the organization. To delete an organization requires deleting the G Suite / Cloud Identity account.

The only items that you can change are who controls the organization and what billing account is linked to the organization.

Comment: I want to delete the entire identity, organization and billing account. Specifically, I already have another identity that I want to own the organization in order to link projects already created in that identity to the organization (specifically to the organization's domain). Easiest way I can see to do it is to scrap this identity and start over since I have nothing in this account yet but the organization and its owned domain.  But I can't delete the identity because it is owned by the org, and I can't see any way to delete the org.

Comment: You missed my entire point. You cannot move the organization. An organization stands at the top, everything else is under it. No account owns an organization. You can change the billing account and delete the old one. You can delete any projects under it. If you no longer want the organization name, remove the billing account and yourself as an IAM member - but remember you will not be able to reuse the same name or domain name. If my comment is not helpful, open a support ticket with Google.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it possible to transfer ownership of the organization to another identity? That may be all I need. But it sounds like I can't do that. If I DO want to delete the organization in order to recreate it under a different account, I still don't see how to do it. As I said, I can't delete the user account apparently because it links to the org. Clicking on delete billing account only says it will remove the billing account and nothing more.

Comment: You cannot. Please reread my answer and comment.

Comment: Ok. To get support I need to enable a support account (which it now tells me will take five days) and possibly have to pay them to get my domain name back? I'm just really confused here.

Comment: If you read my answer and my comments you will understand that you don't need to do what you "think" you need to do. You don't delete organizations. You can change who owns (are members of) them and who pays for them.

Comment: Also, your last comment was unclear. Is it impossible to transfer ownership of an organization to another identity? That may be all I need to do.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can change who are members of an organization. There is no concept of "owner" as you are thinking. Instead, think of who "controls" the organization just like a business.

Comment: I tried adding the other identity as "owner". But then I logged in as the other identity and I see no evidence that it has any association with the organization. Is there something else I need to do to transfer ownership? Specifically, did this in IAM page.

Comment: Yes, delete yourself. Then you will find that you cannot access the organization. However, clarify what you mean by "owner". Google Organizations are managed by IAM. What exactly did you do and exactly what role did you assign? You should contact Google Support. You do not understand the basics and I am afraid that my advice will cause you to "shoot yourself" and then have a bigger problem. While waiting for Google support read the docs on how to manage an organization.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm whether or not it is possible to delete the organization but I can confirm John's answer that I was able to transfer control of it to my other identity after lots of advice from google support. I've had to assign numerous individual role permissions to the other identity to do this. Didn't find the docs particularly helpful. I can see how it's designed to scale up to a large organization but it's a bit intimidating for a one-man operation like mine.
So I'll give John credit for a correct answer.

Comment: Also, [this link](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7332529?hl=en&ref_topic=7555414) hints that it must be possible to delete an organization to release its owned domain, though I have not yet found out how to do it.