# How do I delete a GCP organization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google

Need to delete a GCP organization and everything in it (projects, etc.) - nuke it completely. How can I do that?

Comment: I guess this will resolve your issue https://serverfault.com/questions/977057/how-to-delete-google-cloud-organization

Answer (score 1):

If you delete your [Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6313602?hl=en) account, it will delete your Organization and all resources associated with it. Therefore, if you want to delete your Organization, you can do so by deleting your Google Workspace account. For  [Cloud Identity](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9468554) users, cancel all other Google services, then delete your Google account. This is potentially a very damaging action that might be impossible to fully reverse, so it is recommended to only take this action if you are certain there are no resources in active use.

Here is the public documentation:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization#deleting_an_organization_resource